How might "Grante" > "Cante" > "Cam" have happened in the name "Cambridge"?
Etymonline says only that these changes were "due to Norman influence"
I've never heard of any change similar to gra > ca before, nor anteb > amb. I think for the latter I could imagine perhaps the te getting elided but for the former I can think of no explanation.

I would guess that the initial change Grante Bryċġ > Cantebrigge was due to analogy to the more famous city of Canterbury (although of course, that city gets its name from the Kentish people who lived there, a people who of course were not present in Cambridge, but the etymology of Canterbury may not have been so obvious to the Normans).
From there, syncope of the middle vowel (which has plenty of parallels in other place names) would give *Cantbrigge. At that point you'd just need the t to be lost (not at all unsurprising in such a complex cluster, especially as the first element of the name would not be clear), and then the n to assimilate in place to the b (a regular development).
The shift from short /æ/ to long /eɪ/ only occurred in the name of the city, and not in the backformed name of the river so it must have taken place after the other shifts. This change is also irregular.
So we'd have a development something like:
Old English Grante Bryċġ > Middle English Grentebrige, Cantebrigge (by analogy to Canterbury?) > *Cantbrigge (syncope of medial schwas common in other place names) > *Canbrigge (simplification of complex consonant cluster) > Cambridge (assimilation of the n to the b, and updated spelling) > /ˈkeɪmbrɪdʒ/ (unexplained tensing of the first syllable's vowel).
My guess as to the source of the analogy is definitely not certain, but the main point is that the only unexpected changes are the initial replacement of Gr- with C-, and the tensing of the first syllable's vowel.

How do you explain the long A?

Seems like dissimilatory loss of the first R might have played a role, too.

@trerri that's a good point. Seeing as the river name is /kæm/ not /keɪm/, I would assume it occurred after this process was complete and only affected the name of the city

@TKR that's not completely implausible, but I'd expect some other phoneme to be left behind (e.g. /l/), and it would still leave the /g/ > /k/ unexplained

The tensing of the /a/ in Cambridge is actually really, really weird. Had the river been /keɪm/ and the city /'kambrɪdʒ/, that would have made some sense, since it would fit with the general pattern of pre-cluster shortening that applied in Middle English (even though that might have been a bit too early for the form with -mbr-). The same holds for Cambria (another potential source of analogy), where both /a/ and /eɪ/ are found. It’s like homorganic lengthening, except several hundred years too late.

I stopped reading after "I would guess". Immediate downvote
